# How convert string to sequence 0 an 1 with comma in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a problem with adding a parameter to a 2d array. I want to add this value without string representation, do you have any idea how to do it? Thank you for your response.

```
CORRECT VERSION --
Verdict = '1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,3,180,46,-1'

value = forest.predict([[1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 3, 180, 46]])
```

Here my example, I want to add "Verdict" as a paremeter to "value":

```
Verdict = '1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,3,180,46,-1'
value = forest.predict([[Verdict]])
```

ERROR:

> Blockquote
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,3,180,46,-1'

Comment: do `Verdict = [int(i) for i in Verdict.split(',')]` first so you convert your string to a list of integers, or directly create it as a list of ints. `Verdict = [1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,3,180,46,-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in comment.

`do Verdict = [int(i) for i in Verdict.split(',')]`

first so you convert your string to a list of integers, or directly create it as a list of ints.